# Jquery Ui dialog to show asp.net Gridview row

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui

I am working on an asp.net application where I have a select button and a delete button like this:

' OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');" oncommand="lnkDelete_Command">

Where createShippingAddress should show current record in jquery ui dialog. I am able to show jquery ui dialog like this:

```
 function createShippingAddress() {
            $("#AddShippingPopup").dialog("widget").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
            $("#AddShippingPopup").dialog("open");
            return false;
        }
```

but how to show current record in jquery dialog? Do I need to use web method and call it using jquery Ajax ?

Also, On delete function, I am using confirm box. I want to show jquery ui dialog with ok and cancel buttons and when user clicks Ok, it should delete that record.

I tried this:

```
 OnClientClick="javascript:return deleteItem('<%# Eval("EmployeeID") %>' );"
```

but I am getting error that tag is not well formatted.

How can I pass current record to jquery ui dialog function ?

Comment: Here, jquery Ajax  is your friend buddy.

Comment: @KrunalPatil will it be used for both delete and view ?

Answer (score 0):

Try Something Like

```
OnClientClick='<%# "alert(\"" + Eval("Message") + "\");" %>'
```

OR

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hklk" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Message") %>' onclick="return GiveAlert(this);"></asp:HyperLink>

function GiveAlert(con)
{    
     alert(con.innerHTML);    
     return false;
}
```